# Using M.SE answers in packages

Tags: discussion, packages

I'm working on a Mathematica package, which I intend to publish open source, that incorporates answers I've read or solicited on this site.  For example, @MichaelE2's [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152861/6358) to [my question about taking parts of InterpolatingFunctions efficiently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151845/taking-part-of-an-interpolatingfunction).  This recycled code makes a very small part of the package, which is otherwise original material.

1. Is this acceptable use?
2. What is the best way to give credit to the authors?

For 2, I'm thinking of giving credit / links in the package code and documentation.

Comment: All user content is under the CC-By-SA 3.0 license, so follow that? https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Comment: More licensing info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

Comment: The ShareAlike terms say "If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original."  Does this refer to the whole package or just the functions in question?

Comment: @R.M. I'm confused. What's up with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/164803) about the MIT license and the -280 vote count on that post?  CC seems strange for *code* ...